# C# assign populated array to declared variable

Tags: c#

How do I assign a populated array to a declared variable?

Lets assume we have something like this:

```
    private float[] myArray;

    myArray = {1.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f};
```

I really like to do all the assignments in one go without having to access each individual index or use the Add function.

For example javascript allows me to do this:

```
var myArray;

myArray = [0, 1];
```

Comment: I'm... not sure I follow.

Comment: You have to *create* an array before you assign it. Use `new []{1.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f};`

Comment: Erm ... `private float[] myArray = new float[] { 1.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f };` not suitable for some reason?

Comment: @Whelkaholism I want to do this later.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the question here seems to be _"Why can't you use array initializer syntax to assign an array after declaration?"_.

Comment: @Asperger - you can. `private float[] myArray` to declare, `myArray = new float[]{1.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f};` to assign.

Comment: @Edgars not related to this question.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I actually didn't know you could use that shortcut syntax, thanks :)

Comment: @Asperger read [MSDN: Array Initializers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664573(v=vs.71).aspx): the typeless shorthand (`= { 1, 2, 3 }`) is only allowed at declaration time.

Comment: @Whelkaholism thanks man!